# Why do syslog and uml-net have /home in /etc/passwd?

Tags: users, home-directory

Can someone explain why users syslog and uml-net have `/home` in `/etc/passwd`, even though these directories in `/home` don't actually exist?

```
cat /etc/passwd
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
syslog:x:101:104::/home/syslog:/bin/false
...
uml-net:x:107:111::/home/uml-net:/bin/false
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inherited from old times and to not break stuff. Every line in `/etc/passwd` needs a home (see the addition below). And `/etc/passwd` is something we take as is as part of the Linux system (and not a Debian/Ubuntu specific feature).

In the old days [syslog-ng](https://syslog-ng.org/) was pretty common and that used `/home/syslog/` to create a directory in there for each data source type.

Before the switch to `systemd` using [rsyslog](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man5/rsyslog.conf.5.html), storing logs in `/var/log/syslog` was more common. And [systemd](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man8/systemd-journald.service.8.html) uses `/run/systemd/journal/syslog`.

---

See the man page:

```
/etc/passwd contains one line for each user account, 
with seven fields delimited by colons (“:”). These fields are:

   ·   login name
   ·   optional encrypted password
   ·   numerical user ID
   ·   numerical group ID
   ·   user name or comment field
   ·   user home directory
   ·   optional user command interpreter
```

The encrypted password and user command interpreter explicitly are mentioned as "optional". So I would assume the others are mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the user was possibly created by a malicious crypto mining script, the give away was it was the last user added:

```
...
uml-net:x:114:118::/nonexistent:/bin/false
```

The server was likely infected by this: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/201263/a-process-called-watchbog-is-mining-crypto-currency-in-our-server-how-do-i-st?noredirect=1&lq=1

It also left a ssh publickey login backdoor and various modified cron hooks. Your best bet is to re-install server with latest updates, and revision track /etc/ to help you notice differences - the latter helped me.

Some files had user group `Debian-exim` so likely this server got compromised due to this https://www.linuxtechnews.com/cve-2019-10149-debian-has-released-critical-security-update-for-exim/